# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

Receiving the error:

CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

Not sure how to fix.

Section that's giving me trouble is at:

```
string qty = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("quantity_input"))
{
    qty.Add(int.Parse(item));
}
```

Complete code is:

```
CartItemCollection items = new CartItemCollection();
Cart cart = Core.GetCartObject();
string skus = "";
string debugStr = "";
Product product = null;
string qty = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("quantity_input"))
{
    qty.Add(int.Parse(item));
}
try
{
string[] productNumbers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("ProductNumber");
foreach (string productNumber in productNumbers)
{
debugStr = debugStr + "-p=" + productNumber;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productNumber.Trim()) && !productNumber.StartsWith("Enter Product #"))
{
try
{   //redirect if no product found 
product = Core.GetProductObjectByProductNumber(productNumber);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
debugStr = debugStr + "-e=noproductfound";
continue; //do nothing, process the next user input
}
//check if we have a valid product object, allow virtual and other type(s) for adding directly to cart which may need special handling
if(product != null)
{
debugStr = debugStr + "-t=" + product.ProductTypeName;
if(!product.ProductTypeName.Equals("NORMAL"))
{
//assume VIRTUAL (or other type) and redirect for selecting child/group products or other special handling
form.Redirect("product.aspx?p=" + product.ProductNumber);
}
else
{
debugStr = debugStr + "-a=noattributesadd";
CartItem item = new CartItem(context);
item.ProductId = product.ProductId;
item.Quantity = qty;  
items.Add(item);
}
skus = skus + ";" + productNumber;
product = null;  //reset the product object in case the next product number submitted is invalid
}  //product not null
}  //sanity check for empty or default data
}  //iterate on each product submitted
cart.AddItems(items);
form.Redirect("cart.aspx?skus=" + skus);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
form.AddError("*** ProductNumber provided was not found ***");
form.Redirect("quickorder.aspx?qo=2&e=" + e.Message);
return;
}
```

Comment: What is this: `string qty = new List<int>();` ?

Comment: List<int> qty = new List<int>();

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek Yeah, sorry about that; I inherited the code in this state :(

Comment: `string qty = new List<int>();` You are trying to insert a *IPad in Iphone pouch* Don't you see this?

Comment: Here's a tip:  read the error.

Comment: If you use `var qty = new List<int>();`
Hover mouse over `var` and notice that it shows the correct type, which in this case is: `List<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert a list of integer to a string

```
string qty = new List<int>();
```

maybe doing

```
List<int> qty = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string qty = new List<int>();
```

Should be

```
var qty = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have `List<int>` then your variable type should be `List<int>` and not `string`.

So change:

```
string qty = new List<int>();
```

To:

```
List<int> qty = new List<int>();
```

Now later it appears you need the sum of all the quantities then you can do:

```
int sum = qty.Sum();
```