# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

Receiving the error:

CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'int'

Not sure how to fix.

I am using:

Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5477;

ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5479

Section that's giving me trouble is at:

```
{
    debugStr = debugStr + "-a=noattributesadd";
    CartItem item = new CartItem(context);
    item.ProductId = product.ProductId;
    item.Quantity = qty;  
    items.Add(item);
}
```

Specifically, the item.Quantity = qty; portion

Complete code is:

```
CartItemCollection items = new CartItemCollection();
Cart cart = Core.GetCartObject();
string skus = "";
string debugStr = "";
Product product = null;
List<int> qty = new List<int>();
foreach (string item in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("quantity_input"))

{
    qty.Add(int.Parse(item));
}

try
{
    string[] productNumbers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("ProductNumber");
    foreach (string productNumber in productNumbers)
    {
        debugStr = debugStr + "-p=" + productNumber;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productNumber.Trim()) && !productNumber.StartsWith("Enter Product #"))
            {
                try
                {   //redirect if no product found 
                    product = Core.GetProductObjectByProductNumber(productNumber);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    debugStr = debugStr + "-e=noproductfound";
                    continue; //do nothing, process the next user input
                }
                //check if we have a valid product object, allow virtual and other type(s) for adding directly to cart which may need special handling
                if(product != null)
                    {
                        debugStr = debugStr + "-t=" + product.ProductTypeName;
                        if(!product.ProductTypeName.Equals("NORMAL"))
                        {
                            //assume VIRTUAL (or other type) and redirect for selecting child/group products or other special handling
                            form.Redirect("product.aspx?p=" + product.ProductNumber);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            debugStr = debugStr + "-a=noattributesadd";
                            CartItem item = new CartItem(context);
                            item.ProductId = product.ProductId;
                            item.Quantity = qty;  
                            items.Add(item);
                        }
                        skus = skus + ";" + productNumber;
                        product = null;  //reset the product object in case the next product number submitted is invalid
                    }  //product not null
            }  //sanity check for empty or default data
    }  //iterate on each product submitted
cart.AddItems(items);
form.Redirect("cart.aspx?skus=" + skus);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    form.AddError("*** ProductNumber provided was not found ***");
    form.Redirect("quickorder.aspx?qo=2&e=" + e.Message);
    return;
}
```

Essentially, this is the logic for a Quick Order form. I'm trying to add the qty of each item to the Cart.

Comment: This looks like a follow up question of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815319/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-listint-to-string) but from two different users.

Comment: The error is obvious, the error message tells you exactly what is wrong. We cannot guess what you meant to do. What do you want to achieve with that line?

Answer (score 5):

You problem is in this line:

```
 item.Quantity = qty;
```

`item.Quantity` is an int and qty is a `List<int>`

---

A guess at how to solve (assume all lists are in the same order and enumeration will read them in the same order):

```
int index = 0; // add this line
foreach (string productNumber in productNumbers)
{

 // all the stuff you have already till:

                        item.Quantity = qty[index];

 // all the stuff you have already

   index = index + 1;
}  //iterate on each product submitted
```

NOTE: **I HATE THIS SOLUTION.**  But it will probably work.

A good solution would be to create a data structure that holds both the productnumber and the quantity in the same list.

Comment: Ok, cool. How can I make `List<int>` go into the int of `item.Quantity`?

Comment: @user3490200 - I will make a guess and post an edit.

Comment: Well, no more errors, but my desired result is not functioning.

Essentially, I'm looking to add Products to the Shopping Cart via Quick Order form. 

http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/quickorder.aspx

Comment: @user3490200: Either `qty` has to be an `int` instead of a `List<int>` **OR** `item.Quantity` has to be a `List<int>` **OR** `item.Quantity = qty.Sum();` **OR** pick one item of the list `item.Quantity = qty[someIndex];`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yeah, when I inherited this code, it was hardcoded that `item.Quantity = 1;` and that's it. So I'm trying to add the functionality to input a number and Quick Order more items.

Comment: @user3490200 - I'd say the best bet is to loop over the rows and then pull each form element from that row so you can associate row elements together before make your list.  You could also change the client code to add identifier information to the form elements 
 (a data attribute) as they are created.  Then each form element would know it's index.

Comment: Yes, but cannot assign a whole list to an `int` (to `item.Quantity`). You declared `qty` as a `List<int>`. Either `qty` should just be an `int`, or if it has to be a list, pick one item (one `int`) in this list.

Comment: @Hogan Ok, awesome, how would you do that? If we have to overhaul the entire thing, that's completely ok as long as many of the names stay the same (ID's, classes, names, on the front-end).

Comment: @user3490200 - Since you are not using .net controls it is going to be easier to add the data element -- do some research about the data element (jQuery has a nice intro here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ if you are using jQuery)

Comment: @Hogan Yes, I am using a SaaS essentially. My hands are really, really, tied when it comes to some things as you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/kQySo7u.png Also, we use Bootstrap 3.1.1, and jQuery 1.11

Comment: @user3490200 - so you don't have access to the cart add item javascript?  Then there is no way to do it.